# Send value with form to other document PHP HTML

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a form that will display a product, that will allow me to type in a number of how many i want to buy, and then a submit button that sends tvs and tvno to another document. The first option with the SELECT is working, but the 2nd(my desired display of the "shop") doesnt.

```
<!--FORM NR 1-->

<form action="http://localhost/wordpress/restock/myDbMod/" method="post">
            <table>
                <caption>Sales</caption>
                <tr>
                    <td><select name='tvs'>
<?php
    foreach ($tvs as $tv) {
    printf("<option value='%s'>%s inch, in stock: %s</option>\n"
            , $tv->getScreenSize()
            , $tv->getScreenSize()
            , $tv->getStockLevel());
}
?>
                    </select></td>
                    <td><input type='text' name='tvno'/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Send"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>


<!--FORM NR 2-->

        <form action="http://localhost/wordpress/restock/myDbMod/" method="post">
        <table>
<?php
    foreach ($tvs as $tv) {
    printf("<tr><td name='tvs' value='%s'>%s inch, in stock: %s</td><td><input type='text' name='tvno'/></td>\n"
            , $tv->getScreenSize()
            , $tv->getScreenSize()
            , $tv->getStockLevel());
}
?>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Send"/></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: How about you set the form action to your own file?

Answer (score 0):

Your second form will never work..  ..and you don't need 2 separate forms either.  Combine them both into 1 form as follows:

```
<form action="http://localhost/wordpress/restock/myDbMod/" method="post">
    <table>
        <caption>Sales</caption>

        <tr>
            <td><select name='tvs'>
                <?php 
               foreach ($tvs as $tv) { 
                    printf("<option value='%s'>%s inch, in stock: %s</option>\n"
                    , $tv->getScreenSize()
                    , $tv->getScreenSize()
                    , $tv->getStockLevel());
                } ?>
                </select></td>
            <td><input type='text' name='tvno'/></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
               <!-- A select box will provide better control
                    over 'quantity' than in input box -->
                <select name='tvsno'>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                </select>
             </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Send"/></td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

If you then want to do some processing on the figures, you need to set the form action to be a local file:

```
<form action="myFormProcessor.php" method="post">
```

The form will them submit the values:

```
$_POST['tvs'];
$_POST['tvsno'];
```

to 'myFormProcessor.php' and you can do whatever you need to from there.